# echo jQuery function in PHP as variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok so I am trying to echo an function from jQuery inside of PHP.

I was searching a little bit, I did not found any exact answer but I found that I need to use ajax for it ?

I am not familiar with ajax so I have found this.

```
<?php 
    $status = "<script>
                 $.ajax({ 
                    url: '/',
                    data: {action: 'test'},
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(output) {
                       notifyBox();
                    }
                 });
               </script>";
?>
```

I also have this part somewhere on the page:

```
<?php if(isset($status)) { echo $status; } ?>
```

I am not quite sure if I need all of that to execute the function ?
But it works only if I put jQuery in head of the website.

I usually put all my scripts above `</body>` (at closing tag) and now it bothers me if I have to put all these scripts into head

Because of many pages I cannot separate all scripts now just cause of one page that bother me at the moment.

Can anyone please tell me, how do I call that function without getting console error of undefined '$' because jQuery is loaded at the end of the page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just move that `echo` statement to somewhere AFTER jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Oh my... Now I am blushing :D ! Yeh that was my problem, thank you @Benjam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work so long as you make sure that you put your PHP `if` statement *after* the `<script>` tag that includes jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is being caused by jQuery not being loaded when that variable is echoed.  When Javascript sees a function call, it executes it right then and there.  To prevent this, you will need to echo your variable after jQuery has been loaded.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<?php
    echo $script;
?>
```

OR, you can put your AJAX call into a function that will be called later:

```
<?php
    $script = '<script type="text/javascript">function myFunc() {
        //Call AJAX here
    }
    </script>';
    echo $script;
?>
```

Then later, you can call your function: `myFunc();`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jquery is loaded. This should work:

```
$status = "<script type='text/javascript'>
                $(function(){
                   $.ajax({ 
                    url: '/',
                    data: {action: 'test'},
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(output) {
                       notifyBox();
                    }
                 });
               });
               </script>";
```

Comment: This still has the same problem that `$` is undefined at the time of execution unless jQuery was loaded somewhere before this script.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just put jquery in the header and problems are gone.

Comment: Which is what the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: I can't think of a valid reason not to load jQuery in your header.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready() is also a jquery function, hence, try it with window.onload.